# Error while upgrading Android platform in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, platform

I need to upgrade the version of android platform in cordova. (the playstore reject upgrading my app because it's version is lower than 4.1.1) So I did in terminal "cordova platform update android" and the version of android platform changed to android6.0.0 . But some files in CordovaLib.java is missing and some classes can't import some files. (for example "org.apache.cordova.Utility") I just attached the files in CordovarLib, but the project still has Errors. How can I upgrade the android platform version without error?

Answer (score 1):

1. First Remove Android Platform properly by using following command .

> cordova platform remove android

2. Check that it is properly removed from Project folder or not.
3. Install Android platform again

> cordova platform add android

Try this

Answer (score 0):

First You have to upgrade Java.
then upgrade whitelist plugin: cordova-plugin-whitelist
as well pls. refer the links from Cordova https://cordova.apache.org/news/2016/01/28/tools-release.html

Pls. refer: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/upgrade.html..

if any of above option not worked, use crosswalk plugin for backward compatibility